# Can't get footer to stick at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for a couple of hours now, and looked at several topics about it on stackoverflow and elsewhere. But I can't seem to solve it..

```css
    body {
 background-color: #1a3041;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#757580, #1a3041);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
    }

    html {height:100%}

    .header {
 border-style:solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #fa6800;
 background-color: #717171;
 font-family: open sans;
    color: #c1c1c1;
 padding:0px;
 margin:5px;
 margin-top:20px;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .header h1{
 display:inline;
 font-size:40px;
 padding-left:10px;
    }

    #slogan {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size:20px;
 font-style:italic;
 float:center;
 line-height: normal;
 vertical-align: center;
 padding-right:10px;
 margin-top:0px;

    }

     #menu {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:bold;
 float:right;
 line-height: normal;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 margin-top:10px;

    }

    .main {
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#cdd1d5;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 25px;
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 top:70px;
 min-height: calc(100% - 130px - 35px);
 left:0;
 right:0;
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 left:5px;
 right:5px;
 height:30px;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-style:solid;
 border-bottom: none;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #fa6800;
 background-color:#333333;
 padding-left:10px;
 vertical-align:top;
 font-size:12px;
 font-family: open sans;
    color: #c1c1c1;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    a:link{
 text-decoration:none;
    }

    a:link.title, a:visited.title {
 color:#c1c1c1;
    }

    a:link.menu, a:visited.menu, a:link.current, a:visited.current {
 color:#c1c1c1;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px;
    }

    a:link.lastmenu, a:visited.lastmenu, a:link.lastcurrent, a:visited.lastcurrent {
 color:#c1c1c1;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
    }

    a:link:hover.menu{
 background-color:#fa6800;
 padding:10px;
    }

    a:link:hover.lastmenu{
 background-color:#fa6800;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
    }

    a:link.current{
 background-color:#333333;
 padding:10px;
    }

    a:link.lastcurrent{
 background-color:#333333;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>The Airline Project | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:1250px)" href="mainverysmall.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:1500px) and (min-width:1250px)" href="mainsmall.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:1500px)" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1><a class="title" href="home.html">The Airline Project</a></h1>
    <span id="slogan">Let your dreams fly</span>
    <span id="menu">
    <a class="menu" href="Home.html">Home</a>
    <a class="current" href="TheGame.html">The Game</a>
    <a class="menu" href="TutandTips.html">Tutorials and Tips</a>
    <a class="menu" href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
    <a class="menu" href="http://theairlineproject.net/forum/" target="_blank">Forum</a>
    <a class="lastmenu" href="Aboutus.html">About Us</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

So I have two problems:
-my footer doesn't stick to the bottom of the page
-my 'main' content div doesn't stop before the footer like it should if the window is made too small. (It just continues to the end of the page)

I have read a lot of things that should solve it, but it mostly doesn't work.
Setting the footer to relative for example, sticks it right under the menu. Setting the content to relative sticks it to the middle of the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove Position absolute from the .menu and .footer class style. You will get the desired result. :)

```css
body {
 background-color: #1a3041;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#757580, #1a3041);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
    }

    html {height:100%}

    .header {
 border-style:solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #fa6800;
 background-color: #717171;
 font-family: open sans;
    color: #c1c1c1;
 padding:0px;
 margin:5px;
 margin-top:20px;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .header h1{
 display:inline;
 font-size:40px;
 padding-left:10px;
    }

    #slogan {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size:20px;
 font-style:italic;
 float:center;
 line-height: normal;
 vertical-align: center;
 padding-right:10px;
 margin-top:0px;

    }

     #menu {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:bold;
 float:right;
 line-height: normal;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 margin-top:10px;

    }

    .main {
 background-color:#cdd1d5;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 25px;
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 top:70px;
 min-height: calc(100% - 130px - 35px);
 left:0;
 right:0;
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .footer {
 left:5px;
 right:5px;
 height:30px;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-style:solid;
 border-bottom: none;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #fa6800;
 background-color:#333333;
 padding-left:10px;
 vertical-align:top;
 font-size:12px;
 font-family: open sans;
    color: #c1c1c1;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    a:link{
 text-decoration:none;
    }

    a:link.title, a:visited.title {
 color:#c1c1c1;
    }

    a:link.menu, a:visited.menu, a:link.current, a:visited.current {
 color:#c1c1c1;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px;
    }

    a:link.lastmenu, a:visited.lastmenu, a:link.lastcurrent, a:visited.lastcurrent {
 color:#c1c1c1;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
    }

    a:link:hover.menu{
 background-color:#fa6800;
 padding:10px;
    }

    a:link:hover.lastmenu{
 background-color:#fa6800;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
    }

    a:link.current{
 background-color:#333333;
 padding:10px;
    }

    a:link.lastcurrent{
 background-color:#333333;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>The Airline Project | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:1250px)" href="mainverysmall.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:1500px) and (min-width:1250px)" href="mainsmall.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:1500px)" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1><a class="title" href="home.html">The Airline Project</a></h1>
    <span id="slogan">Let your dreams fly</span>
    <span id="menu">
    <a class="menu" href="Home.html">Home</a>
    <a class="current" href="TheGame.html">The Game</a>
    <a class="menu" href="TutandTips.html">Tutorials and Tips</a>
    <a class="menu" href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
    <a class="menu" href="http://theairlineproject.net/forum/" target="_blank">Forum</a>
    <a class="lastmenu" href="Aboutus.html">About Us</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Under `.footer` in the css, change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6adfc7bs/

Comment: That makes it fixed to the window, I'd like it to be at the bottom of the page. :)

Comment: If you remove the `position` line from both `.footer` and `.main`, does this result in what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: actually, it kind of does.. hah :) Now I just need to have the .main div stretched to the bottom of the page, just above the .footer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you need to change your html.
You need to place the footer inside of your last div see below.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <title>The Airline Project | Home</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:1250px)" href="mainverysmall.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:1500px) and (min-width:1250px)" href="mainsmall.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:1500px)" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="header">
              <h1><a class="title" href="home.html">The Airline Project</a></h1>
              <span id="slogan">Let your dreams fly</span>
              <span id="menu">
                   <a class="menu" href="Home.html">Home</a>
                   <a class="current" href="TheGame.html">The Game</a>
                   <a class="menu" href="TutandTips.html">Tutorials and Tips</a>
                   <a class="menu" href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
                   <a class="menu" href="http://theairlineproject.net/forum/" target="_blank">Forum</a>
                   <a class="lastmenu" href="Aboutus.html">About Us</a>
              </span>

    </div>
    <div class="main">
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <div class="footer">
             <p>footer</p>
         </div>
    </div>



    </body>
```

However this still does not work 100% as the formatting needs to be changed.
I would recommend looking at a bootstrap.
It will make it easier for these types of layouts along with it being already mobile optimized.

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, ok. :) Thanks. Never read about having it inside the other div. How do I make it stick to the bottom of the page now?

Comment: I am confused. Is it not stuck to the bottom of the page now? Or am I misunderstanding the question. Other users have solved the question I think you are asking ? The other answers do not require you move the footer div inside the main div.

Comment: Yeah, the other answers got me there. :) Thanks anyways. Yours got me close too. ;) I'll take a look at bootstrap, but I'd like to learn the coding. ;)

Comment: Be sure to select one of the answers that solved your problem. It is best practise so that other users will stop answering when a question is solved. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can set your footer sticky using postion property by adding sticky value in your css.

```css
body {
 background-color: #1a3041;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#757580, #1a3041);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
    }

    html {height:100%}

    .header {
 border-style:solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #fa6800;
 background-color: #717171;
 font-family: open sans;
    color: #c1c1c1;
 padding:0px;
 margin:5px;
 margin-top:20px;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .header h1{
 display:inline;
 font-size:40px;
 padding-left:10px;
    }

    #slogan {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size:20px;
 font-style:italic;
 float:center;
 line-height: normal;
 vertical-align: center;
 padding-right:10px;
 margin-top:0px;

    }

     #menu {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:bold;
 float:right;
 line-height: normal;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 margin-top:10px;

    }

    .main {
 background-color:#cdd1d5;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 25px;
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 top:70px;
 min-height: calc(100% - 130px - 35px);
 left:0;
 right:0;
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .footer {
 left:5px;
 right:5px;
 height:30px;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-style:solid;
 border-bottom: none;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #fa6800;
 background-color:#333333;
 padding-left:10px;
 vertical-align:top;
 font-size:12px;
 font-family: open sans;
    color: #c1c1c1;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
    }

    a:link{
 text-decoration:none;
    }

    a:link.title, a:visited.title {
 color:#c1c1c1;
    }

    a:link.menu, a:visited.menu, a:link.current, a:visited.current {
 color:#c1c1c1;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px;
    }

    a:link.lastmenu, a:visited.lastmenu, a:link.lastcurrent, a:visited.lastcurrent {
 color:#c1c1c1;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
    }

    a:link:hover.menu{
 background-color:#fa6800;
 padding:10px;
    }

    a:link:hover.lastmenu{
 background-color:#fa6800;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
    }

    a:link.current{
 background-color:#333333;
 padding:10px;
    }

    a:link.lastcurrent{
 background-color:#333333;
 padding:10px;
 padding-right:20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>The Airline Project | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:1250px)" href="mainverysmall.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:1500px) and (min-width:1250px)" href="mainsmall.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:1500px)" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1><a class="title" href="home.html">The Airline Project</a></h1>
    <span id="slogan">Let your dreams fly</span>
    <span id="menu">
    <a class="menu" href="Home.html">Home</a>
    <a class="current" href="TheGame.html">The Game</a>
    <a class="menu" href="TutandTips.html">Tutorials and Tips</a>
    <a class="menu" href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
    <a class="menu" href="http://theairlineproject.net/forum/" target="_blank">Forum</a>
    <a class="lastmenu" href="Aboutus.html">About Us</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```